# Proving number of non zero eigen values.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The statement is :- number of non zero eigen values of a matrix A is atmost rank(A).

Can someone help me to prove this?

I read some of the answers to the question similar to this here but I am not able to understand it fully.

Comment: you have read some answers that you are not able to understand, would you like to tell us what are those to avoid people posting those answers?

Comment: I read one one question about number of distinct eigen values of a matrix with all one's and the answer was 1 because the rank of matrix is 1. I am not able to understand that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a matrix $A$ is diagonalizable, then the algebraic multiplicity of any eigenvalue of $A$ is equal to its geometric multiplicity. In particular, if $A$ is symmetric (Hermitian) or all the eigenvalues of $A$ are distinct, then $A$ is diagonalizable. From rank-nullity theorem, it is known that 
$$\text{rank}(A)+\text{nullity}(A)=\text{dim} (A).$$
Nullity is the dimension of the kernel space of $A$. Meaning the number of linearly independent eigenvectors x for which $Ax=0\cdot x$. So nullity in this case implies the multiplicity of $0$ as an eigenvalue of $A$ and hence rank implies the number of nonzero eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: Here algebraic multiplicity of non zero eigen values + algebraic multiplicities of zero eigen values = n right?

Comment: Considered the cases where algebraic multiplicity=geometric multiplicity of each eigenvalue.

Comment: @Zephyr Number of nonzero eigenvalues including their multiplicities+algebraic/geometric multiplicity of zero eigenvalue = n.

Comment: Can I prove like this ? Let AM and GM denote algebraic and geometric complexities of eigen values. Now AM of non zero eigen values + AM of zero eigen values = n. As AM >= GM, for zero eigen values, AM >= n-r and hence AM of non zero eigen values <=r .

Comment: @Zephyr 'AM of nonzero eigenvalues'!  instead use **sum** of algebraic multiplicities of all nonzero distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. Sum of algebraic multiplicities of non eigen values is same as number of non zero eigen values right?